# Cчитывание значений из MySQL средствами PHP

Tags: php, тестирование, sql

Здравствуйте.

Делаю тест на PHP. Нужно, чтобы надпись "Вопрос № Х" брала значение 'Х' из таблицы. Это я сделал. Но как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на конопке "Следующий вопрос" из таблицы извлекался следующий индекс?

Пытаюсь сделать вот так:

```
function qNumber()
{
    static $counter = 0;
    $connect = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db ("qa7", $connect);
    $tmp_res = mysql_query("SELECT id_q FROM questions");
    $id_q = mysql_result($tmp_res, $counter);    
    ++$counter;
    return $id_q;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.su/functions/?mysql_fetch_array) вместо `mysql_result`. Если перейдете по ссылке, увидите ответ на свой вопрос с примером.

Comment: Так ведь mysql_fetch_array по строкам не перемещается, насколько я понимаю. А понимаю я пока еще мало.<br/>
    
    while ($id_q = mysql_fetch_array($tmp_res))
    {
    return $id_q[1];
    }
<br/>
не возвращает мне id_q = 2, т.к. ищет значение по индексу '1' по полям, а не по строкам. Или я совсем не понимаю? )

Comment: Ваш код 
while ($id_q = mysql_fetch_array($tmp_res)) { return $id_q[1]; } 
неверен, так как при первой итерации while, команда return выбрасывает вас из функции, а соответственно и из цикла. Поробуйте сделать так:
while ($id_q = mysql_fetch_array($tmp_res)) { echo $id_q[0]; }
и вы увидите разницу.

P.S: я же говорил прочитайте внимательно документацию по ссылке

Comment: Так я тоже делал. <br /> В общем, мне кажется я понял, в чем моя ошибка. В первую очередь - это неправильное понимание работы сервер-клиент. В частности, когда я нажимаю кнопочку и надеюсь, что $counter будет увеличиваться. При каждом нажатии функция вызывается заново и все проинициализированные переменные обнуляются. <br /> Думаю, cookies мне помогут.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не разрыхлять себе мозг, делайте так:

```
$q = mysql_query("query goes here, noobs");

  for($c=0;$c<mysql_num_rows($q);$c++){
  echo (mysql_result($q,$c,'column_name'));
  }
```

**Добавление (к комментарию)**.

Ну тоже легко сделать. Тут вопрос не в том, как прочитать конкретное значение из базы, а как плюсовать count, верно? Если да, то пусть у вас вопрос #1 выводится на странице, страница имеет адрес `http://mysite.com/?id=1` , тогда в скрипте нужно прописать, чтобы бралось значение из GET-запроса "id", производился поиск по базе, где `id_q = $_GET['id']` и выводился вопрос с этим номером, а по нажатию кнопки происходил переход по адресу `http://mysite.com/?id=$_GET['id']+1` , т.е. уже адрес перехода будет `http://mysite.com/?id=2` Дальше - воля вашей фантазии (например, чтобы value кнопки был id+1). Не забудьте обезопасить обработку GET-запроса.

Comment: Таким образом он мне выводит все $q. <br />
Итак, еще раз, что мне нужно: <br />
Есть Question #<%=qNumber() %>: <br /> и кнопочка <p><input type="submit" value="Answer" style="width: 100px"/></p> <br />
Нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопке, надпись Question #, становилась Question #1, еще по нажатию - Question #2. '1' и '2' должны браться из таблицы. <br />
$connect = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", ""); <br />
   mysql_select_db ("qa7", $connect); <br />
   $tmp_res = mysql_query("SELECT id_q FROM questions ORDER BY id_q ASC");

Comment: ура, заработало!!! спасибо!

Comment: вообще-то, не совсем. не могу сделать вот это: <br / >
"а по нажатию кнопки происходил переход по адресу http://mysite.com/?id=$_GET['id']+1" <br />
делаю так: <br />
<form name="form1" method="get" action="<? redirect() ?>"> <br / >
<br />
 function redirect()
 {
  header("Location: http://localhost/testphp/client.php?id='".$_GET['id']++."'");
 } <br />

коряво, да? подскажите, пожалуйста, как не коряво сделать.

Comment: Ооочень коряво... Но тут нужно плясать от того, к какой цели вы идете, что вы хотите получить. К сожалению, здесь вам отвечать не смогу постоянно и оперативно. Можете написать мне в ICQ

Answer (score 0):

Перестройте запрос `SELECT id_q FROM questions` в

```sql
SELECT id_q FROM questions 
WHERE id=некоторое число
```

И не забывайте про `mysql_fetch_assign`;